# Nested conditional formatting for self referencing cells

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, self-reference

I am formatting an excel sheet and want to apply a conditional format to a range of cells for when the particular cell matches the one either above or below it, AND when the corresponding cell in the adjacent column matches the cell either above or below it.
an example of the information in the columns:

Name            Ref ID
PER     002-003
PPJ     021-006
PPJ     021-006
PPJ     021-006
RAD     005-013
REI     006-009
RIT     005-085
STJ     002-003
STJ     002-003
TEL     002-013
TEL     007-014
So in this section of the sheet PPJ & STJ should Highlight/fill but TEL should not since while the name matches the REF ID doesn't.

I have tried:

```
=AND(
    OR(
        INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())) = INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN(),-1,0)), 
        INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())) = INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN(),+1,0))
        ), 
    OR(
        INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN(),0,+1)) = INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN(),-1,+1)),
        INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN(),0,+1)) = INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN(),+1,+1))
    )
)
```

but get no response from the cells regarding the formatting changes. I have tried substituting offset for the second OR statement referring to the adjacent column but get an error about too many arguments.

Am I taking an incorrect approach to this or am I missing a step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need that level of complexity. For conditional formatting you can just apply the formula that applies to the top left cell of the range, so if your data is in `D3:E14` for example then you only need to use the formula that applies to `D3`.....so follow these steps

Select the range to format (`D3:E14` in my example)

Apply conditional formatting with the formula that applies to the top left cell of the range, i.e. for your problem

`=AND(OR($D3=$D2,$D3=$D4),OR($E3=$E2,$E3=$E4))`

Choose required format > OK > all done

Excel will implicitly adjust the conditional formatting formula for the whole "applies to" range as if you were dragging that formula on the worksheet, so it will work as required for the whole range

Given your sample data above here's the screenshot of that CF formula applied to your data:

[image]